# Chi-square table

Tags: statistics

I'm new to using chi-square table, and I assume that it should not be hard to use but yet I have some problems with it.

I am due to find the following in a chi-square table: $P(Y>5)$ where $Y$ follows a chi-square distribution with $5$ degrees of freedom. We have not been given any significance level/alpha. How do I use the table to find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the chi-squared table to find the values of $\chi_{n,\alpha}^2$ such that
$$
P(\chi_n^2>\chi_{n,\alpha}^2)=\alpha,
$$
where $\chi_n^2$ is a random variable that has the chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom and $0\le\alpha\le1$.

So we have to choose the number of degrees of freedom (different values of the degrees of freedom are usually rows of the table) and $\alpha$ (different values of $\alpha$ are usually columns of the table) to determine the value of $\chi_{n,\alpha}^2$. For example, if $n=5$ and $\alpha=0.1$, $\chi_{n,\alpha}^2=9.236$ using this [table](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/tbl-chi.html).

Comment: I think I figured it out now, thank's a lot!